# different ScaleTransform for every printer?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, gdi+

Im printing on a labelprinter with 7.5X8 cm labels using the regular GDI+/.NET method and it works fine

```
void pdPrintLabel(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
  Graphics g = ev.Graphics;  

  using (Font smallFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 6),
              mediumFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8),
              bigFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold))
  {
    SizeF smallSize = g.MeasureString("XXX", smallFont);
    SizeF mediumSize = g.MeasureString("XXX", mediumFont);
    SizeF bigSize = g.MeasureString("XXX", bigFont);

    Brush blackBrush = Brushes.Black;

    g.DrawString((bagNumber / 50 + 1) + bagNumber, bigFont, blackBrush, pos);
    // etc
  }
}
```

Now the printer is changed, same model just a different printer. The same code now fills only half the label. Some setting is different I guess.
I could fix this with

```
ev.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1.3f, 1.4f);
```

but only after finetuning/recompiling/testing the arguments. I dont want to change that code every time a new printer is used of course.
So is there an algorithm with which to compute the correct ScaleTransform arguments?

edit:

And on top of that, importing the settings from one printer and exporting them to the other did not change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default scaling mode for printers is GraphicsUnit.Display, one pixel in your code is 0.01 inch on paper.  Which is a resolution-independent scaling mode, output will always have the same size on paper regardless of the printer resolution.  So you never need to use Graphics.ScaleTransform to adjust the scaling yourself.

There's something wrong with the printer driver for this printer, it appears to mis-report the printer resolution.  Which is very rare, particularly so when you use the exact same printer model.  Make sure it isn't a built-in feature of the printer to scale output that just happens to have a different setting on the second printer.  Not entirely unusual for label printers, they like to accommodate software that isn't designed to deal with various label sizes.  You'll need assistance from the manufacturer if you cannot sort it out from the manual.

Comment: after updating all drivers they all have the same behaviour now, so thanks. Its the wrong behaviour though but at least its consistent now :)